# Python to parse log file out to 6 separate files

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, logging

We have this log that comes in as a pdf which I am exporting to a CSV and want to then export those results to separate files for the different logs contained within the pdf.

I have tried parsing as while within another while but I end up in an endless loop.
I've also tried cascading if statements within a for (to pull the lines from the log file).

In the code below I was attempting to loop around the repeated sections using a count but that never seems to be evaluated or I'm not understanding the while correctly.

```
import re
agentss1 = 'Agent Log Time Snapshot'
agentss2 = 'Agent Log Time Detail'
agentss3 = 'Agent Pause Time Detail'
agentss4 = 'Agent Pause Time Reasons'
agentss5 = 'Agent Partial Pause Time'
agentss6 = 'Agent Partial Pause Time Reasons'

end = 'End'
count = 0
with open('Logtime_parts.csv') as file:
    for line in file:
        while count != 5:
            print('Count=' + str(count))
        # if re.search('Agent Log Time Snapshot', line):
        #     print(line)
            line = file.readline()
            if agentss1 in line:
                print('in agentss1')
                while agentss2 not in line:
                    print(line.strip())
                    line = file.readline()
                count += 1
                print(count)
            while re.search('^(?!Agent Pause Time Detail|\\.).*', line):
                print(line.strip())
                line = file.readline()
                # print('while 2')
            count += 1
            print('Count=' + str(count))
            while re.search('^(?!Agent Pause Time Reasons|\\.).*', line):
                print(line.strip())
                line = file.readline()
                # print('while 3')
            count += 1
            print('Count=' + str(count))
            while re.search('^(?!Agent Partial Pause Time Detail|\\.).*', line):
                print(line.strip())
                line = file.readline()
                # print('while 4')
            count += 1
            print('Count=' + str(count))
            while re.search('^(?!Agent Partial Pause Time Reasons|\\.).*', line):
                print(line.strip())
                # print('In 2 end ' + str(count))
                line = file.readline()
                # print('while 5')
            count += 1
            # debugging
            print('Count=' + str(count))
            print('/n/n')
        # while re.search('^(?!Agent Log Time Detail|\\.).*', line) or re.search('^(?!End|\\.).*', line):
        #     words = line.split()
        #     print('In end '+ str(count))
        #     print(line.strip())
        #     count += 1
        #     # print(words[7].replace(',', ''))
        #     line = file.readline()
    count = 0
    print('out of loop')
    line = file.readline()
file.close()
```

I feel that I've gone down the wrong rat hole with this now.

The log file is structure as below were the first lines to the Agent Log Time Detail Records exist once then the sections below that are repeated for any number of agents.

```
Agent Log Time Snapshot,,,,,
Agent Pause Count,Pause Time (H),Pause Time %,Logon Count,Logon Time (H),Log Time %
agent1 77,17:05:18,1.60%,23,182:34:19,3.60%
agent2 47,88:56:03,8.31%,12,416:30:28,8.22%
agent3 188,27:57:27,2.61%,19,159:00:08,3.14%
Agent Log Time Detail Records - agent1,,,,
"#" ,Start Time             ,End Time               ,Duration   ,Disposition
1   ,Oct 08 2019 08:32 am   ,Oct 08 2019 05:03 pm   ,8:30:20    ,Not Specified
2,Oct 02 2019 11:50 am,Oct 02 2019 09:00 pm,9:09:48,Not Specified
3,Oct 03 2019 11:52 am,Oct 03 2019 09:00 pm,9:07:50,Not Specified
4,Oct 05 2019 09:04 am,Oct 05 2019 05:00 pm,7:56:13,Not Specified
5,Oct 07 2019 07:47 am,Oct 07 2019 05:02 pm,9:15:13,Not Specified
Agent Pause Time Detail Records - agent1,,,,
"#" ,Start Time             ,End Time               ,Duration   ,Disposition
1   ,Oct 08 2019 08:32 am   ,Oct 08 2019 08:32 am   ,0:00:02    ,
2   ,Oct 08 2019 02:45 pm   ,Oct 08 2019 02:51 pm   ,0:06:04    ,Break
3   ,Oct 08 2019 03:00 pm   ,Oct 08 2019 03:23 pm   ,0:22:36    ,Break
4   ,Oct 08 2019 04:37 pm   ,Oct 08 2019 04:50 pm   ,0:12:54    ,Break
Agent Pause Time Reasons Details - agent1,,,
Pause Reason    ,Pause Count    ,Pause Time (H) ,Pause Time %
""              ,1              ,00:02          ,0.08%
Break           ,3              ,41:34          ,99.92%
Agent Partial Pause Time Detail Records - agent1,,,,,
"#" ,Start Time             ,End Time               ,Duration   ,Queue              ,Disposition
1   ,Oct 08 2019 08:54 am   ,Oct 08 2019 12:28 pm   ,3:34:25    ,Green_Team ,Auto Paused
2   ,Oct 08 2019 12:28 pm   ,Oct 08 2019 02:51 pm   ,2:23:15    ,Green_Team ,Auto Paused
3   ,Oct 08 2019 04:11 pm   ,Oct 08 2019 04:50 pm   ,0:38:39    ,Green_Team ,Auto Paused
Agent Partial Pause Time Reasons Details - agent1,,,
Pause Reason    ,Pause Count    ,Pause Time (H) ,Pause Time %
Taking other call,109,34:42:55,69.84%
Auto Paused,55,14:42:41,29.60%
Not Specified,1,00:00,0.00%
Meeting,1,16:39,0.56%
Agent Log Time Detail Records - agent2,,,,
"#",Start Time,End Time,Duration,Disposition
1,Oct 01 2019 08:31 am,Oct 01 2019 05:07 pm,8:36:37,Not Specified
2,Oct 02 2019 11:53 am,Oct 02 2019 08:57 pm,9:03:27,Not Specified
3,Oct 03 2019 09:07 am,Oct 03 2019 06:11 pm,9:04:03,Not Specified
Agent Pause Time Detail Records - agent2,,,,
"#",Start Time,End Time,Duration,Disposition
1,,Oct 01 2019 08:57 am,0:26:12,Not Specified
2,Oct 01 2019 01:00 pm,Oct 01 2019 01:10 pm,0:09:36,Break
3,Oct 01 2019 01:14 pm,Oct 01 2019 01:55 pm,0:41:04,Break
4,Oct 03 2019 12:47 pm,Oct 03 2019 12:51 pm,0:04:15,Break
5,Oct 03 2019 01:08 pm,Oct 03 2019 02:07 pm,0:59:23,Break
Agent Pause Time Reasons Details - agent2,,,,,
Pause Reason,Pause Count,Pause Time (H),Pause Time %,,
Agent Partial Pause Time Detail Records - agent2,,,,,
"#",Start Time,End Time,Duration,Queue,Disposition
1,Oct 01 2019 08:44 am,Oct 01 2019 08:57 am,0:13:03,Green_Team,Auto Paused
2,Oct 01 2019 02:23 pm,Oct 01 2019 03:45 pm,1:21:51,Green_Team,Auto Paused
3,Oct 01 2019 03:45 pm,Oct 01 2019 04:32 pm,0:47:03,Green_Team,Auto Paused
4,Oct 01 2019 04:32 pm,Oct 02 2019 12:25 pm,1:06:46,Green_Team,Auto Paused
5,Oct 02 2019 12:25 pm,Oct 02 2019 02:04 pm,1:39:18,Green_Team,Auto Paused
Agent Partial Pause Time Reasons Details - agent2,,,
Pause Reason,Pause Count,Pause Time (H),Pause Time %
Agent Log Time Detail Records - agent2,,,,
"#",Start Time,End Time,Duration,Disposition
1,Oct 01 2019 08:31 am,Oct 01 2019 05:07 pm,8:36:37,Not Specified
2,Oct 02 2019 11:53 am,Oct 02 2019 08:57 pm,9:03:27,Not Specified
3,Oct 03 2019 09:07 am,Oct 03 2019 06:11 pm,9:04:03,Not Specified
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if my nesting of the if statements was part of the issue. Was able to get it working with some help. Needs some testing but believe it's a good solution to my problem.

```
agentss1 = 'Agent Log Time Snapshot,,,,,'
agentss2 = 'Agent Log Time Detail'
agentss3 = 'Agent Pause Time Detail'
agentss4 = 'Agent Pause Time Reasons'
agentss5 = 'Agent Partial Pause Time'
agentss6 = 'Agent Partial Pause Time Reasons'

with open ('Logtime_parts.csv', 'rt') as myfile:  # Open file lorem.txt for reading text
    for myline in myfile:                    # For each line, read it to a string
        if agentss1 in myline:
            while agentss2 not in myline:
                print(myline.strip())
                myline = myfile.readline()
        if agentss2 in myline:
            while agentss3 not in myline:
                print(myline.strip())
                myline = myfile.readline()
        if agentss3 in myline:
            while agentss4 not in myline:
                print(myline.strip())
                myline = myfile.readline()
        if agentss4 in myline:
            while agentss5 not in myline:
                print(myline.strip())
                myline = myfile.readline()
        if agentss5 in myline:
            while agentss6 not in myline:
                print(myline.strip())
                myline = myfile.readline()
        if agentss6 in myline:
            while myline != "":
                print(myline.strip())
                myline = myfile.readline()
```